# appcache in html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-appcache

I have the following HTML source code:

```
<html manifest="demo_html.appcache">
<body>

<script src="demo_time.js"></script>

<p id="timePara"><button onclick="getDateTime()">Get Date and Time</button></p>

<p><img src="img_logo.gif" width="336" height="69"></p>

<p>Try opening <a href="tryhtml5_html_manifest.htm" target="_blank">this page</a>, then go offline, and reload the page. The script and the image should still work.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And file demo_html.appcache

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2012-02-21 v1.0.0
/logo.gif
/demo_time.js
```

When I click the HTML page the cache does not work. I do not understand why? Any ideas?

Comment: "When i click this page in file html cache does not work." --> Can you elaborate?  What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Serve the appcache with `Content-Type: text/cache-manifest`.